# USB 3.0 working but not USB 2.0

Tags: drivers, usb

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 and since then, none of my USB 2.0 ports have been working but my USB 3.0 ports are working (both front and rear). All of the ports worked on my previous Fedora installation. The devices I am plugging in are all low power: a receiver for my mouse, a webcam, and a mic.

Motherboard: Gigabyte 990FXA-UD3

```
$ dmidecode
Handle 0x0012, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J3A1
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: USB1
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J3A1
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: USB2
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0014, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: J3A1
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: USB3
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

$ lspci
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
```

Comment: Try enabling IOMMU at UEFI settings and adding the boot argument `iommu=soft` and/or install a newer kernel (the IOMMU problem was solved at the kernel level sometime around 16.10 so installing the current 16.04.3 should be enough)

Comment: I tried the `iommu=soft`. I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with kernel 4.10.0-42-generic. Maybe I need to play around in some of the BIOS settings to enable IOMMU there? My installation is in the MBR of the drive, I didn't set up an EFI partition. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Not the issue, usually, but can be. UEFI mode should be preferred for better handling of the hardware (if unsigned driver are needed then also disable Secure Boot). There's no point in using Legacy ("BIOS") installs unless it's really needed and it isn't, Ubuntu supports UEFI mode.